# Order of methods and NoMethodError

Tags: ruby

Here's my code.

```
print "What's your first name"
first_name = gets.chomp.capitalize!

print "What's your last name"
last_name = gets.capitalize!.chomp
```

If I have `capitalize!.chomp` with a capitalized string (i.e `Johnson, Williams`), I get an error on the last line:

```
undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

If I either type more capital letters, type all lowercase, or have the `chomp` method before `capitalize!`, the code runs fine.

Can someone explain this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the documentation on these very carefully to see how they work as there are often surprises. In this case [`capitalize!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) will return `nil` if no changes are made.

So your first version is correct:

```
gets.chomp.capitalize!
```

That's also the most reasonable order of operations: You should trim your data before operating on it.

It's also worth noting that using the in-place version is not necessary as you're assigning to a variable anyway:

```
first_name = gets.chomp.capitalize
```

Given the nature of names, capitalizing might be a bad plan anyway. What about "de Lorean"?

Comment: The first version is not correct if the variable is to be assigned a string.

Comment: When I want to chain methods that may return `nil` as in this case, I do like this: `first_name = gets.tap(&:chomp!).tap(&:capitalize!)`. But I have never tested if it is any more efficient than `first_name = gets.chomp.capitalize`.

Comment: @sawa That's a very irregular use of `tap`. Maybe you mean `try`?

Comment: No. There is no point in using a heavy `try` for the purpose of using destructive methods for efficiency.

Comment: `tap` is supposed to be used for a mind-chain inspection, not as a way to alter things in place. Not sure what you're going for there, but it seems like the wrong approach. The simplest version, `gets.chomp.capitalize`, is probably considerably faster. `try` is sometimes overkill, but in cases where a method *might* return `nil` and you want it to just deal, it's the best plan.

Comment: `try` is active support the question does not have a rails tag

Comment: In addition, when only an intermediate `nil` is the issue, the safe navigation operator is much better than the Rails `try`.

Comment: @sawa Agreed about the safe navigation operator, but that requires a fairly new version of Ruby to use. The old method of `try` isn't bad. You can use ActiveSupport in any project, or simply port the method in if you need it, the implementation is very small.

Answer (score 2):

`capitalize!` modifies the string in place and returns a `nil` object.  So when you try to do chain the methods together `gets.capitalize!.chomp` then `capitalize!` returns a `nil` object which does not have a `chomp` method.

However, if you use `capitalize` instead then the method returns a modified copy of the string (which is an on which you can perform `chomp`).

```
last_name = gets.capitalize.chomp
```

Comment: "there is no object on which to perform chomp."---Sort of misleading. There is always a return value (object), this case `nil`. It is the method `chomp` that doesn't exist (for `nil`), not that `nil` that doesn't exist.